# Calculation of total duration with regards to multiple timestamp with multiple mode and model in tableau

Tags: time, tableau-api, duration, calculation

As shown below is a small portion of my data:

```
Model,Timestamp,long,lat,mode
x,14/1/2018 1:06:12 PM,103.764280,1.331031,1
x,14/1/2018 1:06:12 PM,103.764253,1.330950,1
x,14/1/2018 1:06:11 PM,103.764242,1.330870,1
x,14/1/2018 1:06:11 PM,103.764226,1.330784,2
x,14/1/2018 1:06:10 PM,103.764210,1.330709,2
x,14/1/2018 1:06:10 PM,103.764189,1.330645,1
x,14/1/2018 1:06:09 PM,103.764178,1.330575,1
x,14/1/2018 1:06:09 PM,103.764172,1.330495,1
x,14/1/2018 1:06:08 PM,103.764162,1.330414,1
y,14/1/2018 1:06:08 PM,103.764162,1.330355,1
x,14/1/2018 1:06:07 PM,103.764156,1.330275,1
y,14/1/2018 1:06:07 PM,103.764146,1.330205,2
y,14/1/2018 1:06:06 PM,103.764140,1.330108,1
y,14/1/2018 1:06:06 PM,103.764124,1.330039,1
```

I would like to ask if there is any ways to calculate the total duration of  each model(x and y) based on the timestamp in TABLEAU?

This is a vehicle tracking data so i would like to track each model's runtime on the road

UPDATE!!!!!!:Created Max and Min timing with respect to the model

{Fixed[Model],[Mode]: Max[Timestamp]} - Max Ts

{Fixed[Model],[Mode]: Min[Timestamp]} - Min Ts

Then created Hour, Minutes and second field to piece it up together to show the total duration. As I'm trying to look for the duration of each mode of each model, the duration actually overlaps.

An example with diff data set:
e.g. The whole duration of my Model X is 5 hours 3 second. My mode 1 has a total of 5hours 3 second, but inbetween this 5 hour, it actually transit to mode 2 for 10mins.

But tableau capture mode 1 as 5 hour 3 seconds , adding both mode 1 and 2, it should give me my Model X total timing.

But it actually overlaps.

|            1hour(Mode 1)           |  5mins(Mode 2)  |          1hour(Mode 1)             | 1min(Mode2) |   2min(Mode1)  |   4mins(Mode 2)  |           2hours 56mins 3second(Mode1)            |

The actual data will have lots of transition, I would like to piece up all Mode 1's total duration and Mode 2's duration.

But currently it gives me overlaps duration

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: As i am very new to tableau, I am still researching on methods to start

Comment: How is the duration calculated in the above?

Comment: do you need total duration of x (MEans first timestamp of x - last timestamp of x) and in the same way for y? is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes correct! I have several models that i want to track per day @Siva